# Discrete mathematics: domain questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Okay, so I have another practice problem for discrete mathematics. I again apologize in advance if there's a similar question, but discrete math is still very new to me. This problem goes "Let the domain of variable x be the set of all integers. Prove or disprove."

The equation is $\forall x,(x+1)^2 \ge 1 $

I thought I had disproved this because while plugging 0, any positive integer, or most negative integers in for x would indeed make $(x+1)^2$ greater than or equal to 1, plugging in -1 would make $(x+1)^2$ into 0. However, the feedback I got suggests I was wrong, but there's no explanation for what I did wrong. Did I miss something?

Comment: Make sure that the domain of $x$ is ${\mathbb Z}$, and not ${\mathbb N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It suffices to show that $\exists{x} \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $(x+1)^{2} < 1$. As $(x+1)^{2} \geq 0$ $\forall{x} \in \mathbb{Z}$, we want an integer $x$ s.t. $(x+1)^{2} = 0$. You correctly deduced that $x = -1$ is a counterexample to the statement $\forall{x}, (x+1)^{2} \geq 1$.

It might be worth discussing the feedback with your professor. Intro to Proofs type classes are picky about details for a reason. It's possible to have the right idea, but lose points for poor form or imprecise writing.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what the correct form would be? I'd hate to have this problem again, but still not have any feedback for what I my writing flaws are.

Comment: "Correct form" is not the term I would use. Folks develop their own writing styles for proofs. In intro to proofs classes, different instructors emphasize different formats, and it comes across to students as anal and too picky. If and when you move onto higher level theory and math classes, the instructors are not so anal about the little things. Your instructor is really the best person to give you feedback about his or her expectations. In particular, when you get graded work back, don't be afraid to seek clarification on how you can improve.

Answer (score 1):

$(x+1)^2 \geq 0$ for all $x$ is correct.